# How to avoid device names from being truncated to 16 characters in /dev/disk/by-label?

Tags: linux, hard-disk

I have already read [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56291/what-causes-dev-disk-by-label-to-be-populated) about how `/dev/disk/by-label/` is filled with symlinks to the system drives.

I am using KDE, and Dolphin File Manager shows all those drives with those 16-char names, it lets me to rename them, but it only works until the next reboot.

I want to know how to avoid names from being truncated to exactly 16 characters if possible.

Comment: What you see there are the filesystem lables. So to change them permanently you need to use a filesystem-specific utility. Which filesystems are you dealing with?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa 3x ext4 (LVM-LV-mapped) partitions

Answer (score 1):

To change the filesystem label on ext4 filesystems, use the tune2fs utility.

For example, if the LVM logical volume is */dev/vg0/lv-whatever*, then you can change the label with the command: `tune2fs -L "New Label" /dev/vg0/lv-whatever`

Comment: You didn't read the question, I know about commands and utils like `tune2fs` or `e2label`, but all of them truncate the new label to 16 characters. The question is "how to avoid that".

Comment: First, don't be an ass. The folks around here generously provide assistance FOR FREE! You can't avoid the truncation because 16 characters is the limit for filesystem labels, according to the tune2fs manual.

Comment: I'm not as ass, since I am asking something that you don't answer to, I didn't ask for a tool that allows me to change the labels, but a method how to avoid the truncation. But this, your last comment actually answer the question. Now, how can it be avoided is the point of this post.